# STM32F4 GPIO IDR

Tags: gpio, stm32f4

I am learning STM32F407 MCU but confused with its Input Data Register. This register is 32 bits which 0-15 bits are read only and the remain bits are reserved. My question is that the register is defined with defaulf value of 0x0000XXXX in data sheet. XXXX are "undefined" in datasheet. What does really mean "undefined" term ? 
Here is an example:
if (GPIOA->IDR & 0x0001)
      GPIOD-ODR |= 0xF000;

So undefined register bits can cause turning the LEDS on while I do not pressing the button ?

Thanks....

Comment: Which state should the bits have after reset? - You cannot define the bits' state in the chip's documentation because they represent the corresponding input signal which can be anything.

Comment: So they're just undefined. I mean they will not change in run time, remains undefined until pressing a button. (I mean undefined is not 0 or 1 just undefined.) ?

Comment: Undefined here means the bits are either 1 or 0 but the chip does not itself enforce one or the other upon reset.

Comment: Okey I got it. Thank you very much!